# How to return XML from ASP.NET 4 Web API to ASP.NET Core 2 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, http, parsing

I have two applications. A requesting client application written in ASP.NET Core 2 (we can call the "client"), and a responding/API application written in ASP.NET 4 Web API (we can call the "server"). The former is making a request to the latter, and I'm looking to receive, and subsequently parse, XML from the web API application.

The client is making an HTTP request using the following setup:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(communicatorUri)
};
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/xml");

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await this.HttpClient.PutAsync(
    "api/customer",
    new StringContent(customerDetails.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
);
```

It's sending through JSON, and expecting an XML response. The server is processing the JSON, and hopefully returning an XML response:

```
string response = "<note>Well formed XML string</note>";
return Ok(response);
```

Where this response arrives back at the client:

```
string responseString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(responseString);
```

However, every time the response arrives back, it appears as if it's been double-encoded with `\"`'s. For example, it may look like `"\"<note attr=\\\"test\\\">Well formed XML string</note>"`, and so subsequently it is obviously no longer valid XML, so parsing fails via a thrown exception.

Where do I start to actually fix this? I'm a bit confused as to whether I need to make changes with my requester, or my response, or even both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the controller on the server:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
  //process the request 
  .........

  string XML="<note><body>Message content</body></note>";
  return new HttpResponseMessage() 
  { 
    Content = new StringContent(XML, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") 
  };
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is correct. I did try this, but I was still returning an `IHttpActionResult` by wrapping the above `HttpResponseMessage` in `Ok()`, which is not a great idea. Using `HttpResponseMessage` directly like this is the way to go.